# Remotely display each item in a list to the monitors of each computer in a lab

Tags: javascript, java, list, remote-access, remote-desktop

I use Netop Vision software in my computer lab that has the ability to display a custom message to all monitors, but what I would like is to be able to display each students name on the monitor of their assigned computer.  Somehow I would like to write a program that would read from a list of student names and assigned computer names (or IP addresses), and display the name to the corresponding monitor in the lab. I have experience programming in Java, PHP, SQL, and javascript, but networking is new to me. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do they have to logon to these computers or sign in?

Comment: They will log on, but this is especially useful the first day that they come to the lab and have never logged in before.

Comment: I should also clarify that I would like the name to be in large font and override the logon screen.  Essentially this is way to direct new users to their assigned computer when the walk in the room. I could certainly walk around and tape a hand written card on each monitor, but as a programmer, as always, there HAS to be a better way :)